# Android, исключение при попытке получить результат startActivityForResult в onActivityResult

Tags: android, activity

Передаю строковый литерал через putExtra, но не могу извлечь его в onActivityResult. Всё делается в одной активити. Я получаю либо это:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo
```

,либо не получаю ничего, строка не доходит. Подскажите, почему мой код не работает?

Приложение позволяет сделать снимок и сохранить его в память телефона. В onActivityResult пытаюсь передать путь до временного файла, который создаётся в takeAPhoto.

**takeAPhoto**

```
private void takeAPhoto(String PATH, int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile;
        ...
            if (photoFile != null) {
                ...
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("file", photoFile.getAbsoluteFile());
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        } else {
                ...
        }
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (data.getStringExtra("file") != null) {
        Log.i("GoodResult1", "WE DONE");
        File file = new File(data.getStringExtra("file"));
        Log.i("GoodResult2", file.getName());
    }
    recreate();
}
```

Я пробовал много реализаций onActivityResult(через Bundle, getExtras и getIntent). Приведённая выше - один из последних вариантов. Как написать правильно, чтобы передача осуществилась успешно? Что я понимаю не так?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А почему Вы считаете что приложение "Камера" должно вернуть назад эту запись? Оно создаёт новый интент, кладёт в него то что должно и отдаёт вызвавшей активности. Вы должны сами "запомнить" этот файл в поле класса, а в `onActivityResult` проверить `resultCode` и использовать файл из поля.

Comment: А причем тут "Камера"? В доках читаю: `putExtra: Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example...`. То есть в моём понимании я могу сопроводить своей записью вообще любой intent. А для `getStringExtra:Returns the value of an item previously added with putExtra(), or null if no String value was found`. То есть мне не важно какой придёт intent, я могу извлечь из него запись, если она там есть. Про то чтобы запомнить файл - попробую, благодарю.

Comment: Вот именно что _если она там есть_ - Вы не можете положить данные в один интент, а забрать из другого.

Comment: Так у меня только один интент: `takePictureIntent`. Поэтому я не делаю проверку `resultCode` в `onActivityResult`. И запись в интенте есть, я сам её положил: `takePictureIntent.putExtra("file", photoFile.getAbsoluteFile());`, а вот пытаюсь забрать: `File file = new File(data.getStringExtra("file"));`. Или у меня всё же не один интент? Для пробы я ставил проверку по кодам, результат был аналогичный.

Comment: 1) `takePictureIntent`, 2) `data` - считать-то умеем? Вы же не из `takePictureIntent` файл обратно требуете, а из `data`.

Comment: Точно, мне что - то в голову ударило что `data` - это содержание `takePictureIntent`. Благодарю. Оформите ответ, я отмечу его.